# Parsing escaped xml tags in java

Tags: java, xml, soap

I have a performance problem when transforming soap response. The core of the problem as I could identify it is in improper xml format of soap response. The soap response has xml tags escaped (eg. `&lt;SomeNodeName&gt;some text&lt;/SomeNodeName&gt;` instead of `<SomeNodeName>some text</SomeNodeName>`). As I could understand java (java.xml library which I use) is treating escaped tags as one "big" tag. To be able to successfully parse soap response I have to "unescape" all the characters using "StringEscapeUtils". This is the the actual bottleneck. I have to transform each node to string, unescape it and write it back to as a node.
The performance comes in question when response is around 1MB+. 
The exact response is like this (without envelop) :

```
<GetData_PodjetjeReportResponse>   <GetData_PodjetjeReportResult>
    &lt;BisnodeWebServiceData&gt;
      &lt;Status&gt;1&lt;/Status&gt;
        &lt;Data&gt;
          &lt;PodjetjeFinancni&gt;
            &lt;Item&gt;
              &lt;Leto&gt;2016&lt;/Leto&gt;
              &lt;TipSubjekta&gt;1&lt;/TipSubjekta&gt;
              ........
            &lt;/Item&gt;
            &lt;Item&gt;
              &lt;Leto&gt;2015&lt;/Leto&gt;
              &lt;TipSubjekta&gt;1&lt;/TipSubjekta&gt;
              ........
            &lt;/Item&gt;
            ........
          &lt;/PodjetjeFinancni&gt;
        &lt;/Data&gt;
      &lt;/BisnodeWebServiceData&gt;
    </GetData_PodjetjeReportResult> </GetData_PodjetjeReportResponse>
```

My question would be. Is there any way to get around this node-string-node process and use original escaped soap response to parse it?

Thanks.

Comment: Two other possibilities. 1 figure out why the tags are escaped and fix that. 2 run the doc through a filter to unescape all the tags. In either case you then have a simple xml doc to work with.

Comment: I have no way of influencing response as it is provided by web service provider. Will try with filter approach. Thx.